# Using ID of the last inserted row in a statement (Derby)

Tags: sql, derby

i'm trying to get the ID of the last inserted record to use it in a further statement. The initial insert query is like this:

```
insert into app.customer(cust_name, pass) values ('tester', '123123');
```

But when i use IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL():

```
select IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() from app.customer;
```

for some reason i get 9 duplicate rows as a result, which is confusing. 
I need the ID of the added customer so i can use it in a new query right after that.

```
insert into app.coupon_customer(coup_id, cust_id) values(coupon_id_value, customer_id_value)
```

Is it possible to combine the insert query with the IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a derpy expert but can't you do:

```
insert into app.coupon_customer(coup_id, cust_id) 
values(coupon_id_value, IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL())
```

If you do:

```
select IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() from app.customer;
```

you are just selecting the last inserted id FOR EACH row in app.customer.
So yes that gives you 9 duplicate rows if app.customer contains 9 rows.

Comment: yea, i just tangled myself with that select query, your code worked for me fine.